# Select max value row(s) based on 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

How to select row(s) with the max value in either c2nd or 3rd column?

In first case, the max value 30 is in row3, hence returning row3

```
A, 1, 10
B, 2, 11
C, 30, 12

=> C, 30, 12
```

In second case, max value is on row2, hence returning row2

```
A, 1, 10
B, 2, 31
C, 30, 12

=> B, 2, 31
```

In last case, max value is on both row2 and row3, hence returning both

```
A, 1, 10
B, 2, 31
C, 31, 12

=> B, 2, 31
=> C, 31, 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `GREATEST` in the `ORDER BY` clause and then `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` to only query the table once:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY GREATEST(column2, column3) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
```

Before Oracle 12, you can use the `RANK` analytic function (again, only querying the table once):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY GREATEST(column2, column3) DESC) AS rnk
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (c1, c2, c3) AS
SELECT 'a', 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 3, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b | 2 | 3 |
| c | 3 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xnZFEcLo)

Comment: Does not seem to work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c09b3/4

Comment: @learning_python_self It works from Oracle 12 (which is now 10 years old). I've updated with a second solution that works before Oracle 12. Both of them only query the table once.

Comment: High quality response, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
with m as (select max(greatest(col2, col3)) as g from t)
select * from t cross join m 
where t.col2 = m.g or t.col3 = m.g
```

Comment: Works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c09b3/7

Answer (score 1):

Or just use a `where` clause to check for qualifying rows using an uncorrelated subquery

```
select * 
from t
where (select max(greatest(c2,c3)) from t) in (c2, c3)
```

Comment: Imho the most readable solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c09b3/17